# Border width decreases select form-control element's height

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

Setting custom border style and -width affects the height of a `select` element that contains Bootstrap's `form-control` class.

However the same class doesn't affect an `input` element's height with `form-control` (as expected).

See [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/u5jn7ptm/) to replicate the following:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-6">
    <input type="text" id="textbox" class="form-control border-foo" />
    Height: <span id="textbox-height"></span>
  </div>
  <div class="col-6">
    <select id="select" class="form-control border-foo">
      <option>test</option>
    </select>
    Height: <span id="select-height"></span>
  </div>
</div>

.border-foo {
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 30px;
}
```

Am I missing/misusing a class here?

Comment: I cannot see anything that in your code that indicates you're using Bootstrap.

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**  preferably in a **Stack Snippet**. Although you have provided a link, if it was to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem. See [**Something in my website/demo doesn't work can I just paste a link**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reset selectbox `appearance` and `height` value added by bootstrap then it will work as expected, please have a look at the below working snippet, hope it helps :)

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<style>
  select.form-control.border-foo:not([size]):not([multiple]) {
    height: auto;
  }
  .border-foo {
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 3px;
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    -moz-appearance: none;
    appearance: none;
  }
</style>
<br>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-6">
    <input type="text" id="textbox" class="form-control border-foo" />
  </div>
  <div class="col-6">
    <select id="select" class="form-control border-foo">
      <option>test</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks @Girisha C, the `height: auto` does the job! See an [updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/m9Lesqk4/). Any more info on why we need this only for the `select` element specifically with the `form-control` class?

Comment: @JvR, it has nothing to do with class `form-control`, even if your remove that class from both `input` and `select` it will do the same, maybe you’ve noticed that the various browsers represent fields and inputs differently, each browser has different default styles. at the moment there are no inputs that would look and act the same on all browsers with the same style rules applied. Just wait till you need to style a file input...now that's some real fun!

Comment: It definitely is something in Bootstrap that's causing the height to be adjusted. Look at [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gwej16rb/) without it, and the heights will stay consistent as you adjust the `border-width`.

Comment: yes, as per your jsfiddle there is some minor difference in height value, actually bootstrap is trying to fix that by adding `height`, in your case if the `border: 3px solid`, then height value should be `height: calc(2.25rem + 6px);`, that will also fix the issue